# How to run multiple Java projects using single command in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I have four Java projects in my Eclipse's workplace, and each one of them producing information that is needed to my another project.

I don't need to run each java project by click on each project and click run as java application.

I need a way that I call only one command or click on run only one time and all project are running.

I have four Java projects having name `JavaSED1`, `JavaSED2`, `JavaSED3` and `JavaSED4`. They all are related in a way that `JavaSED2` depends on `JavaSED1` and `JavaSED3` depends on `JavaSED2`, and so on.

! [image: Following is the snapshot of all projects for better clarity]

Comment: What's the question, or what's the problem (apart from the quite incomprehensible question in the title)?

Comment: @ nbro - i want to achieve above mentioned topic. Basically question is how to run multiple java project using single command ?

Comment: What do you mean by "running multiple Java projects"? Do you know that the main entry point of any Java program is the `public static void main` method?

Comment: @ nbro - Do u have clarity or need more explanation ?

Comment: @Saurabh: No you can not do that Since at run time only JVM has to load  only one main method

Comment: @nbro - i know that entry point for java is public static void main.

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan I am not sure, but maybe what you want to do is  to use threads...

Comment: @nbros - I figure out the solution

Comment: @AnandDwivedi . U can also check my solution. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i figure out the solution. Let say we have four different java project and we want functionality like we need to run only one project/run command only single time (in order to avoid click or to run each project individually in order to avoid headache in testing ).Select only one project lets say JavaSED1 and go to properties->java build path->projects->add remaining three projects. So up to this we have done with dependency. Now in JavaSED1 main method provide call for rest of three projects main method and simply its working.